# How can I modify a static humanoid asset?

Tags: unity, 3d, graphics

I am new to Unity 3D. I bought an asset from the Unity Asset Store recently. It came in a "walking" stance. I was wondering if it was possible to modify this stance to become fully supine; so can I modify the legs so that they are straight and next to each other?

I am not sure if I can do this or not in Unity, or if I have to download Blender or Maya to do this.

I have already tried forcing a stance change, through vertex snapping, but I am not having any luck with that. I have also tried editing the Character Joint settings, but I think that is if I wanted to animate the model, which I don't.

This is what my character looks like currently:

[image: "walking" character]

I edited the character as per DMGregory's suggestion, but I am having trouble reimporting it back into my scene:

[image: "supine" character]

Comment: Inside the character's transformation hierarchy, do you see any transforms labelled "skeleton" or "armature", containing individual bone transforms? Try rotating some of those bones (being careful to rotate them about their pivot) - does that help you adapt the post the way you need?

Comment: No I can't find those transforms. I have been searching for some time now. How do I get to the character's transformation hierarchy? And what kind of Asset is it (Model, Prefab, etc.)?

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of what you see in the Hierarchy window when inspecting your character in your game scene.

Comment: Ok. I kind of got the bones rotated, but I am still not sure how to reimport it into my scene.

Comment: You don't need to "reimport it back into your scene" — the object you're showing in your screenshot is already in your scene. No reimport needed — it's imported, it's there.

Comment: How do I replace the walking model with the supine model?

Comment: They're the same mesh, so I don't understand what you mean by replacing the model. Do you mean you want to save a prefab in the supine pose by dragging it from your hierarchy window into the assets folder?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got everything resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to make the humanoid static and usable in my project. As a summary of the steps I took to solve this problem:

1. I had to get to the Skeleton of my imported prefab, so I clicked on my imported prefab, selected the Rig tab, changed Animation Type to "Humanoid", and selected "Apply".
2. In the Transform menu, I rotated the Left and Right Upper Shoulder bones until the model was supine.
3. I saved that new mesh into my Project as a prefab.
4. I was able to drag that prefab into my scene.